# Sending out twitter retweets with Python

Tags: python, twitter

I wanted to know if this was possible- I want to use Python to retweet every tweet a person sends out. If yes then how can I implement this?

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, [python-twitter](http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/) does *not yet* support the Twitter [Retweet REST call](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/post/statuses/retweet/:id).

You'll have to make that call directly yourself (using direct calls to api._FetchURL) or apply the patch in [issue 130](http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/issues/detail?id=130) to add support.

You're better off with using [tweepy](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/tweepy); read the [API documentation](http://tweepy.readthedocs.org/en/v3.2.0/), there is a handy `retweet(id)` method for retweeting.

Quick and dirty example:

```
import tweepy
auth = tweepy.BasicAuthHandler("username", "password")
api = tweepy.API(auth)
for status in api.user_timeline('someuser'):
    api.retweet(status.id)
```

This will retweet the last 20 statuses from `someuser`. You'll want to do some more coding to prevent it from retweeting those same messages again next time you run the script though.

Edit: Twitter no longer accepts BasicAuth authentication, and you'll have to use the OAuth authentication exchange to get a authorisation token. Changing the example above to use OAuth would detract from the retweet API point I was trying to make, see the [Tweepy OAuth tutorial](http://tweepy.readthedocs.org/en/v3.2.0/auth_tutorial.html#oauth-authentication) for an extensive tutorial.

Comment: @Martijn- got an error- `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ret.py", line 7, in <module>
    for status in api.user_timeline('worshiprene'):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/tweepy/binder.py", line 184, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/tweepy/binder.py", line 167, in execute
    raise TweepError(error_msg, resp)
tweepy.error.TweepError: [{'message': 'Basic authentication is not supported', 'code': 53}]
`

Comment: I said it was a quick and dirty example. :-) Use OAuth instead, want me to update the example?

Comment: also, you no more need to care about retweeting same message again, just handle the exception: `TweepError: [{'code': 327, 'message': 'You have already retweeted this Tweet.'}]`

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to retweet anything the people you follow tweet.You can also retweet all of the public tweets.

Use this link : https://github.com/joshthecoder/tweepy
you will know how to do it in a very simple way .

Answer (score 1):

Here's the OAuth "Quick and dirty" method, please keep in mind that you will need to have Tweepy installed for this to work.

```
import tweepy

api_key = 'your_key'
api_secret = 'your_secret_key'
access_token = 'your_token'
access_secret = 'your_secret_token'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(api_key, api_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

for status in api.user_timeline('someuser'):
    api.retweet(status.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

The newest version of python-twitter allows you to retweet with the command

api.PostRetweet(tweet_id)

where api is a logged-in api and tweet_id is the id of the tweet you want to retweet.